# Read File, Search for Term and replace all line of this term

Tags: c#, winforms, replace, streamwriter

I've done a little research but I couldn't find the answer for my question.

I've got this code for search for a term and replace it.

The point is, In my application I want to choose some files and folders path and then write that path's to my .properties file so that "values" is always changing.

In my `.properties` file I've got `db.host=localhost` and I want to change it for the host name that user choose like `db.host=myhost`. There's my code:

```
 string originalFile = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\build.properties";
        string outputFile = @"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\build1.properties";
        string searchTerm = "db.host=";
        string replaceTerm="db.host=" + tbhost.Text ;

        string tempLineValue;
        using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(originalFile))
        {
            using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
            {
                using (StreamWriter outputWriter = File.AppendText(outputFile))
                {
                    while (null != (tempLineValue = inputReader.ReadLine()))
                    {
                        outputWriter.WriteLine(tempLineValue.Replace(searchTerm, replaceTerm));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So right now if I search for `db.host=` and change it for `"db.host=" + tbhost.Text` the result in my file is `db.host=myhostoldhost` supposing that my `tbhost.Text=myhost` and the oldest value is "oldhost". So what I need is to find `db.host=` delete all line and then write in that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Following code before you write to file

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\s");
String[] tokens = r.Split(tempLineValue);
string settings = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
{
   if (tokens[i].Contains(searchTerm))
   {
       settings = tokens[i];
       break;
   }
}
if (settings != string.Empty)
    outputWriter.WriteLine((tempLineValue.Replace(settings, replaceTerm));
else
    outputWriter.WriteLine(tempLineValue);
```

Assumption: your host has only one word.

Answer (score 0):

usercr I have the code like this:

```
using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(originalFile))
        {
            using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
            {
                using (StreamWriter outputWriter = File.AppendText(outputFile))
                {
                    while (null != (tempLineValue = inputReader.ReadLine()))
                    {

                                                    Regex r = new Regex(@"\s");
                        String[] tokens = r.Split(tempLineValue);
                        string settings = string.Empty;
                        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
                        {
                           if (tokens[i].Contains(searchTerm))
                           {
                               settings = tokens[i];
                               break;
                           }
                        }
                        outputWriter.WriteLine((tempLineValue.Replace(settings, replaceTerm)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And I've got the expception "string cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldvalue"

Comment: I have fixed in my above code.Need to check if any line has db.host configuration, that can be done by checking settings is empty.

Comment: Thanks usercr, I'm doing that in my job and now I'm at home so tomorrow I'll try the code.